# How to change url scheme of Search component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, url, jroute

How can I change the url scheme appearing for Search Component in Joomla.

When a search is done url goes like:

```
http://localhost/joomlaproject/component/search/?searchword=destination&searchphrase=all&Itemid=219
```

I need to change the url like

```
http://localhost/joomlaproject/search/?searchword=destination&searchphrase=all&Itemid=219
```

how can i change this?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

Goto joomla administrator -> System -> Global configuration -> Here you can enable the sef url and check your url.

Comment: i have turned on the settings still no change

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by creating a hidden menu for Search component. Here is the link which i followed
    https://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs